# Java program to programmatically find the sums of mathematical series

Tags: java

I need to write a Java program that does the following - For each of the first ten positive integers, raise them all to power 1, then find that sum. Then raise them all to power 2, and find the sum. Then raise them to power 3, and then find the sum and so on and so forth and then just print out the sums. Basically,
1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 3<sup>1</sup> + ... + 10<sup>1</sup> = sum1
1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + ... + 10<sup>2</sup> = sum2
1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + 10<sup>3</sup> = sum3
1<sup>4</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 3<sup>4</sup> + ... + 10<sup>4</sup> = sum4
1<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 3<sup>5</sup> + ... + 10<sup>5</sup> = sum5
and just print out the values of sum1 to sum5.
Here's what I've tried;

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (double power=1;power<=5;power++)
    {
        for (double n=1;n<=10;n++)
        {
            double result = (Math.pow(n, power));
        if (n%10==0)
        {
            double sum=0;
            sum+=result;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }

    }
}
}
}
```

I do get five outputs, but not quite the desirable ones. It just prints out

```
10.0
100.0
1000.0
10000.0
100000.0
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: this line: `if (n%10==0)` means that you're only summing up powers where the base number is divisible by 10.  So, for instance, if the series is 1^2 + 2^2 . . . 10^2, you're ignoring everything except the10^2 term.  You should initialize `sum` *outside* of your inner loop, and remove the if-statement entirely.  Just sum up everything calculated inside the inner loop, and use the `println` outside of the inner loop after it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need `if` block in inner for loop which is ignoring the values other that `10` and second you just need variable in outer `for` to store the result

```
for (double power = 1; power <= 5; power++) {

        double sum = 0;
        for (double n = 1; n <= 10; n++) {
            double result = (Math.pow(n, power));
            sum=sum+result;

        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy when you use IntStream ranges:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(1, 6) // second param is exclusive
             .map(power ->
                      IntStream.range(1, 11)
                               .map(n -> (int) Math.pow(n, power))
                               .sum())
             .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

> 55
>   385
>   3025
>   25333
>   220825

The heavy lifting is done by this bit:

```
IntStream.range(1, 11)
    .map(n -> (int) Math.pow(n, power))
    .sum()
```

it loops over the ints from 1 to 10, raises each of them to the current power, and sums them up together. The outer stream just loops over the powers and pipes the output to `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 0):

public class Numrat {

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    double sum=0;
    for(int power=1; power<6; power++) {

        for(int j= 1;j<11; j++) {
            double variable=(Math.pow(j, power));
            sum +=variable;


        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```

}